# Sphinx docstring: specify class type instead of object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sphinx

In Sphinx, say that you had a function that takes one parameter. Your docstring might look like the following:

```
class A(object):
    pass

def funct1(a_object):
    """
    :type a_object: A
    """
    pass

funct1(A())
```

However, what if you aren't passing an object of class A, but rather the class "A" itself? How would that docstring look?

```
class B(object):
    pass

def funct2(b_class):
    """
    :type b_class: ?????
    """
    pass

funct2(B)
```

Comment: well if you want to just state the type of the param it is expected, you are expecting a class. if you try `type(B)` you will get that it's of type : `type`. by that logic, wouldnt it be `:type b_class: type`

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I guess `type` would be the correct type... the reason I was doing this was to improve PyCharm's type inference. I had hoped that there was a generic I could use (e.g. `:type b_class: type[B]`), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've often thought this was a minor weakness in Sphinx's type annotations as `type` certainly isn't specific enough (though it is correct) -- You could have lots of instances of `type` that don't actually provide the required interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this should work for type hinting, even if it isn't 100% technically accurate:

```
class B(object):
    pass

def funct2(b_class):
    """
    :type b_class: () -> B
    """
    pass

funct2(B)
```